# Yelp Account Creation Faild to Solve Captha with 2captha Api

Tags: python, api, yelp

Hi I am stuck with Solving captha using 2captha api python.... captha solved correctly by 2captha api.. but once submit the form it will show another captha as detect a bot..
here is video capture what happend : https://youtu.be/7MEhJlTtvFI

here is my code

def create_account(firstname,lastname,email,password, save_file = "yelp_accounts.csv"):
        passport_version = False
        apikey = ""
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\YelpBot\drivers\chromedriver.exe")

```
    driver.get("https://www.yelp.com/signup")
    first_name = firstname
    last_name = lastname
    driver.find_element_by_id("first_name").send_keys(first_name)

    driver.find_element_by_id("last_name").send_keys(last_name)
    mail=email
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(mail)

    pwd = password
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(pwd)
    zip="84480"
    driver.find_element_by_id("zip").send_keys(zip)
    driver.find_element_by_id("signup-button").click()
    sleep(5)

    googlekey="6Le5OSYTAAAAADy8seTrWT0eqpS795iV32Gm9Ag1"
    # Add these values
    API_KEY = apikey  # Your 2captcha API KEY
    site_key = googlekey  # site-key, read the 2captcha docs on how to get this
    url=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[3]/div/div/div/iframe"))).get_attribute("src")

    print url



    s = requests.Session()

    # here we post site key to 2captcha to get captcha ID (and we parse it here too)
    captcha_id = s.post("http://2captcha.com/in.php?key={}&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey={}&pageurl={}".format(
        API_KEY, site_key, url)).text.split('|')[1]
    # then we parse gresponse from 2captcha response
    recaptcha_answer = s.get(
        "http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={}&action=get&id={}".format(API_KEY, captcha_id)).text
    print("solving ref captcha...")
    while 'CAPCHA_NOT_READY' in recaptcha_answer:
        sleep(5)
        recaptcha_answer = s.get(
            "http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={}&action=get&id={}".format(API_KEY, captcha_id)).text
    recaptcha_answer = recaptcha_answer.split('|')[1]
    print recaptcha_answer

    driver.execute_script(
        "arguments[0].style.display='inline'",
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="g-recaptcha-response"]'
        ),
    )

    driver.execute_script(
        'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "%s"'
        % recaptcha_answer
    )


    #sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_id('signup-button').click()
    sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should probably add some delays before entering each character in each field, as site may analyze your typing speed.

Second of all, some sites require an additional request(s) to be sent when captcha is solved. In this case you should find and execute the callback function.
Here is the easy way: https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#callback
Or the hard way: https://captchaforum.com/threads/problem-with-invisible-recaptcha-v2-callback-function-at-mail-com-sign-up-page.56/